# Send Novell GroupWise instant message via Java?

Tags: java, message, novell, instant, groupwise

It this possible or is there an API for this?  From Novell's website, there's a GroupWise API, but I don't see any methods for sending instant messages, only e-mails.

I simply want to create a Java program that will send an instant message to someone who's online using Novell GroupWise Messenger.

Answer (score 0):

I am told it is possible to get access to a limited API, but requires signing an NDA.

If you look on [this page](http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/author/364.html), you can find contact info and I can put you in touch with the appropriate people to get started on that path.